# im trying to find maximun and minimum between the rows in 2d array---- the minimum value code seems correct but not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    int total, average, maximum, mininum;

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int tab[5][5] = { { 111, 2, 30, 4, 500 }, { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }, 
        {34, 54, 78, 9, 23,},
        { 65, 12, 98, 3, 78 }, { 34, 89, 23, 98, 45 } };
    string name[5] = { "EMP1:EREN", "EMP2:ARMIN", "EMP3:MIKASA", "EMP4:LEVI", "EMP5:CONNIE" };

    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {

        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
            //cout<<total<<"\n";
            cout << tab[c][a] << "\n";
            3 total = total + tab[c][a];
            b = tab[c][a];
            for (tab[c][a] = 1; tab[c][a] >= 300; tab[c][a]++);

            if (tab[c][a] >= x) {
                x = tab[c][a];
            }

            for (tab[c][a] = 1; tab[c][a] < 5; tab[c][a]++);

            if (tab[c][a] < b) {

                y = tab[c][a];
            }
        }
        average = total / 5;
        cout << "I.D number " << name[c] << " \nThe total amount of sale:" << total;
        cout << "\nThe average sales is:" << average;
        cout << "\nThe Maximum sales is:" << x;
        cout << "\nThe Minimum sales is:" << y << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (tab[c][a] = 1; tab[c][a] >= 300; tab[c][a]++);`  This just sets `tab[c][a] = 1` because 1 is smaller than 300 so the condition `tab[c][a] >= 300` is never true;

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly c-style and your logic is not very clear, I just turned it into morden cpp-style with the usage of `accumulate`, `minmax_element`, we can also change the 2-d array into `vector` or `std::array`, which is left for you.

STL algorithms used:

- [accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) for sum up
- [minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) for get minimal value and maximal iterator together

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  constexpr size_t kColomns = 5;
  constexpr size_t kRows = 5;
  int tab[kRows][kColomns] = {{111, 2, 30, 4, 500},
                   {10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
                   {34, 54, 78, 9, 23},
                   {65, 12, 98, 3, 78},
                   {34, 89, 23, 98, 45}};
  string name[kRows] = {"EMP1:EREN", "EMP2:ARMIN", "EMP3:MIKASA", "EMP4:LEVI",
                    "EMP5:CONNIE"};

  for (int c = 0; c < kRows; c++) {
    auto total = std::accumulate(&tab[c][0], &tab[c][kColomns], 0);
    auto average = total / kColomns;
    auto [min_iter, max_iter] =
        std::minmax_element(&tab[c][0], &tab[c][kColomns]);
    cout << "I.D number " << name[c] << " \nThe total amount of sale:" << total;
    cout << "\nThe average sales is:" << average;
    cout << "\nThe Maximum sales is:" << *min_iter;
    cout << "\nThe Minimum sales is:" << *max_iter << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I.D number EMP1:EREN
The total amount of sale:647
The average sales is:129
The Maximum sales is:2
The Minimum sales is:500
I.D number EMP2:ARMIN
The total amount of sale:150
The average sales is:30
The Maximum sales is:10
The Minimum sales is:50
I.D number EMP3:MIKASA
The total amount of sale:198
The average sales is:39
The Maximum sales is:9
The Minimum sales is:78
I.D number EMP4:LEVI
The total amount of sale:256
The average sales is:51
The Maximum sales is:3
The Minimum sales is:98
I.D number EMP5:CONNIE
The total amount of sale:289
The average sales is:57
The Maximum sales is:23
The Minimum sales is:98
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aYWxG7r43)

Comment: Nicely done. The only nit I see is a readability problem where you loop `for (int c = 0; c < kColomns; c++)`. You may want to make clear this is a loop over the rows where you have used `kColomns` only because it is a square matrix and it saves creating a `kRows` variable with the same value. (though that may be worth the extra 4-bytes here)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much for pointing out it!

Comment: That is much easier to read -- well done.

Comment: @PUMPKIN  You are welcome! then you may consider accept my answer or wait for a better one.